# Remove duplicate record if it contains certain value in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have this table:

```
Student | Task | Result  | Reason
Jim     | 3    | Success | NULL
Jim     | 4    | Success | NULL
John    | 3    | Success | NULL
John    | 2    | Failed  | Task finished too late
Bill    | 5    | Success | NULL
Bill    | 7    | Failed  | Not enough knowledge
Bill    | 6    | Unknown | Asked StackOverflow to do his homework
```

I want to filter out the successful tasks of each Students here IF said student has one or more failed or unknown task. If they didn't fail/unknown at all I only need to see the successful ones.

So my expected result would be:

```
Student | Task | Result  | Reason
Jim     | 3    | Success | NULL
Jim     | 4    | Success | NULL
John    | 2    | Failed  | Task finished too late
Bill    | 7    | Failed  | Not enough knowledge
Bill    | 6    | Unknown | Asked StackOverflow to do his homework
```

I've tried using a group by and the MIN(Result) but then I end up with one record no matter the success/fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple use case of a window function referenced via a Common Table Expression (CTE):

### Query

```
declare @t table(Student varchar(10),Task int,Result varchar(10),Reason varchar(50));
insert into @t values('Jim' ,3,'Success',NULL),('Jim' ,4,'Success',NULL),('John',3,'Success',NULL),('John',2,'Failed ','Task finished too late'),('Bill',5,'Success',NULL),('Bill',7,'Failed ','Not enough knowledge'),('Bill',6,'Unknown','Asked StackOverflow to do his homework');

with s as
(
    select *
          ,sum(case when Result <> 'Success' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Student) as NonSuccesses
    from @t
)
select Student
      ,Task
      ,Result
      ,Reason
from s
where Result <> 'Success'
    or NonSuccesses = 0;
```

### Output

```
+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| Student | Task | Result  |                 Reason                 |
+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| Bill    |    7 | Failed  | Not enough knowledge                   |
| Bill    |    6 | Unknown | Asked StackOverflow to do his homework |
| Jim     |    3 | Success | NULL                                   |
| Jim     |    4 | Success | NULL                                   |
| John    |    2 | Failed  | Task finished too late                 |
+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

declare    @t    table    (Student    varchar(10),    Task    int,   Result varchar(10),    Reason    varchar(50));
insert into @t values('Jim' ,3,'Success',NULL),('Jim' ,4,'Success',NULL),('John',3,'Success',NULL),('John',2,'Failed ','Task finished too late'),('Bill',5,'Success',NULL),('Bill',7,'Failed ','Not enough knowledge'),('Bill',6,'Unknown','Asked StackOverflow to do his homework');

;with a as
(
select Student,count(distinct result)cn
from @t
group by Student
)
select *  from a b
join @t c on b.Student=c.Student where cn=1 or  Result<>'success'

---or

select * from @t where Result<>'Success' or Student in (select Student from @t group by student having count(distinct result)=1)